# Card showing in the background on animation (KivyMD) (How to get rid of it)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Okay, I want to animate the cards in my app. Because it gets to cluttered to have all the fields and everything in one card. I would like to avoid changing screen, and just animate the card itself. The app is a "register user" - kind of thing. But when I try to animate the cards, the first card (card_1) lurks in the back of everything during the animation. Or rather a copy of it with lower opacity... Can't figure out why he wont leave.

**Picture:**

[image: Card in background]

**.kv file:**

```
<RegisterUser>:
    name: "registeruser"
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Mauri"
            right_action_items: [["account", lambda x: root.goto_userlogin()]]
        BoxLayout:
    FloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            id: card_2
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: [0.9, 0.6]
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: [1, 0.1]
                MDLabel:
                    halign: "center"
                    text: "Registrera 2"
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 0.8
                    font_size: "25dp"
                    bold: True
                MDLabel:
                    halign: "center"
                    text: "Användare"
                    color: 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8
                    font_size: "15dp"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDTextField:
                    id: email
                    hint_text: 'Namn'
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    helper_text: "Email Krävs"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
                    mode: "rectangle"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDTextField:
                    id: email
                    hint_text: 'Efternamn'
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    helper_text: "Email Krävs"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
                    mode: "rectangle"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDRaisedButton:
                    id: btn_institution
                    text: "Välj institution"
                    on_release: root.show_institutions()
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                MDLabel:
                    id: inst_label
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDTextField:
                    id: pwd
                    icon_left: 'key-variant'
                    hint_text: 'Ålder'
                    mode: "rectangle"
                    max_text_length: 2
                    input_filter: "int"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDRaisedButton:
                    id: btn_sexes
                    text: "Välj Kön"
                    on_release: root.show_sexes()
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                MDLabel:
                    id: sex_label
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    size_hint: [0.7, 0.5]
                    text: "Nästa"
                    font_size: "20dp"

        MDCard:
            id: card_1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: [0.9, 0.6]
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: [1, 0.1]
                MDLabel:
                    halign: "center"
                    text: "Registrera"
                    color: 0, 0, 0, 0.8
                    font_size: "25dp"
                    bold: True
                MDLabel:
                    halign: "center"
                    text: "Användare"
                    color: 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8
                    font_size: "15dp"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDTextField:
                    id: email
                    hint_text: 'Namn'
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    helper_text: "Email Krävs"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
                    mode: "rectangle"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDTextField:
                    id: email
                    hint_text: 'Efternamn'
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    helper_text: "Email Krävs"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
                    mode: "rectangle"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDRaisedButton:
                    id: btn_institution
                    text: "Välj institution"
                    on_release: root.show_institutions()
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                MDLabel:
                    id: inst_label
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDTextField:
                    id: pwd
                    icon_left: 'key-variant'
                    hint_text: 'Ålder'
                    mode: "rectangle"
                    max_text_length: 2
                    input_filter: "int"
                    pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                spacing: "20dp"
                MDRaisedButton:
                    id: btn_sexes
                    text: "Välj Kön"
                    on_release: root.show_sexes()
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                MDLabel:
                    id: sex_label
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.8, 0.1]
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    size_hint: [0.7, 0.5]
                    text: "Nästa"
                    font_size: "20dp"
                    on_release:
                        root.anim_to_next(card_1, card_2)
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: [0.4, 0.1]
```

**.py file:**

```
class RegisterUser(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        self.sql_cursor = app_users.AppUsers()
        self.all_inst = self.sql_cursor.fetch_all_institutions()
        self.selected_inst = -1
        self.selected_sex = -1


    def callback_for_inst_items(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])
        self.ids["inst_label"].text = args[0]
        self.selected_inst = args[1]
        print(self.selected_inst)


    def show_institutions(self):
        bottom_sheet_menu = MDListBottomSheet()
        for i in range(len(self.all_inst)):
            bottom_sheet_menu.add_item(
                self.all_inst[i][1].capitalize() + " (" + self.all_inst[i][2] + ")",
                lambda x, y=i: self.callback_for_inst_items(
                    self.all_inst[y][1].capitalize() + " (" + self.all_inst[y][2] + ")", self.all_inst[y][0]
                ),
            )
        bottom_sheet_menu.open()

    def callback_for_sexes_items(self, *args):
        self.ids["sex_label"].text = args[0]
        self.selected_sex = args[1]
        print(self.selected_sex)


    def show_sexes(self):
        bottom_sheet_menu = MDListBottomSheet()
        sex = ["Man", "Kvinna", "Annat"]
        for i in range(3):
            bottom_sheet_menu.add_item(
                sex[i],
                lambda x, y=i: self.callback_for_sexes_items(
                    sex[y], y
                ),
            )
        bottom_sheet_menu.open()


    def anim_to_next(self, card_1, card_2):
        anim_1_1 = Animation(opacity=0,duration=0.5)
        anim_1 = Animation(pos_hint={"center_x": -0.5},duration=0.7)

        anim_2 = Animation(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5})
        anim_1_1.start(card_1)
        anim_1.start(card_1)
        anim_2.start(card_2)
```

**Question:**

How to get rid of the "third" (it's the card with id "card_1") that lurks in the background? Why is it there?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Cannot seem to replicate the problem. It all works fine when I try to.

Comment: I'd recommend manually animating the position using a Clock.schedule_interval() and completely removing the widget when you don't want it

Comment: Okay, so if I change the opacity of the filled rectangle in canvas.before, the box gets painted over, this may be a temporary solution, but I would rather want it to "be gone".

Comment: Since you cannot provide a [mcve], you might check that you are not inadvertently loading your `kv` file twice. That can happen if you name the `kv` file in accordance with the auto-loading feature of kivy, and also load the file explicitly using `Builder`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot! Hope you'll have a pleasant day

Answer (score 0):

## Kind of a Solution:

In **.kv-file** I changed opacity of canvas.before Rectangle to 1:

```
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0.3, 0.6, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

However, I still don't know why or how this happened.

## Solution Provided by John Anderson

"Since you cannot provide a minimal reproducible example, you might check that you are not inadvertently loading your kv file twice. That can happen if you name the kv file in accordance with the auto-loading feature of kivy, and also load the file explicitly using Builder."